# How to fix this Invalid cross-thread access issue?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I got a feedback crash log from my user, there is no clue for it, can you help me how to fix this kind of problem?

```
Crash time: 2014-02-10,20:17:01:589
-----: ---------------------------------------  ----------------
App version: 1.2.5129.43070
OS Version: 8.0.10211.0
Device Name: A620e
Device Manufacturer: HTC
Device Firmware Version: 1325.00.10702.1402
Device Hardware Version: 1325.00.10702.1402
Power Source: External
Network: Unavailable
-----: ---------------------------------------  ----------------
Exception message: Invalid cross-thread access.
-----: ---------------------------------------  ----------------
Stack trace:    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
   at System.Windows.Application.get_Host()
   at System.Windows.Application.Application_Exiting(Object sender, EventArgs
e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex,
Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr
unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String
eventName)
```

Comment: share some code as well

Comment: Please post the code for your `Application_Exiting` function.

Comment: In my Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e) function, it is empty, nothing in it.